# BlogForUmbraco Comment moderation not working

Tags: comments, umbraco, umbraco-blog

I installed BlogForUmbraco on Umbraco 4.7 and neither "comment moderation" on dashboard nor adding a comment on a blog post are working. Does anybody experienced a similar problem ?

Comment: Hi Yohann,

I'm currently in charge of the Blog4Umbraco core, and I am aware of a number of issues with B4U on Umbraco 4.7. I am looking to rectify with a release soon, although I cannot be definitive about when that release will be. Best, Benjamin

Comment: After installing UComment it magically worked. I can't wait any further as I need to release the website soon. Thank you for your reply.